# Javascript: using the apply method

Tags: javascript, apply

Here's my code:

```
var add = function(x,y) {
  console.log(x + y);
}


var delay = function(func, wait) {
  var inner = function() {
    return setTimeout(function() {
      return func.apply(inner, arguments);
    }, wait);
  }
  return inner;
};

var delayAdd = delay(add, 500);

delayAdd(100,200); //should log 300 to console after 500ms
                   //instead, it logs NaN
```

I suspect the problem is in line 9: `return func.apply(inner, arguments);` 
My intention is for `add` to be called on the arguments in `inner`, which are defined in the last line `delayAdd(100,200)`. However, this does not seem to be happening. Why is this, and how can I fix this issue?

Comment: The result from the `apply` call is only returned to the `timeOut`, however `setTimeout` returns a reference to the timer, not the result from whatever is returned inside it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `arguments` keyword is specific to the scope it's being referenced from. As it is, you're passing the arguments from your `setTimeout` function. What you need to do is save a reference from the scope you want, and pass that:

```
   var inner = function() {
      var args = arguments;
      return setTimeout(function() {
         return func.apply(inner, args);
         ...
```